# No trailing slash results in a 404 error in Flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, flask

-- Resolved without changing anything. Will update when I know what caused it to temporally not work --

I made a route to a URL without a trailing slash on Flask. This should work according to the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#variable-rules):

```
timestamp = "temptime"

@app.route('/js/searchindex<time>.js')
def searchindex(time):
    return render_template('searchindex.js')
```

What happens is that the URL gets redirected to the URL with trailing slash, which obviously results in a 404 error. So `http://127.0.0.1:5000/js/searchindextemptime.js` becomes `http://127.0.0.1:5000/js/searchindextemptime.js/`.

I am aware that I can set the slashes to not-strict to avoid the 404, but I really want without trailing slash.

Comment: Quick comment because it may look weird to dynamically generate a `js` file like this: I use frozen flask to generate a static site with client-side search. The search-index is inside a `js` file to keep it cached. Every new iteration of the site gets a newly timestamped `js` file to update the browser caches.

Comment: Flask only redirects to the same URL with a trailing slash appended if the route path has a trailing slash. Yours doesn't. Maybe there is another route that is matched (and then for some reason returns 404), or it isn't Flask doing the redirect?

Comment: @Rloqvist - That would work, but I want the route to be **without** trailing slash in this case.

Comment: @FlorianWinter - It does not seem to match another route. Please check the full paste at: https://pastebin.com/qWxx2dc3 . Also everything works fine when I start adding a slash.

Comment: Maybe try `time = "temptime"` and make sure the browser isn't caching

Comment: Must have been something of the like, although I made sure to do a hard refresh. Problem does not recur. Really happy with the solution of a timestamped `js` file and clientside search seems to scale well to a thousand blogposts. Ps. updated to `timestamp = '{:%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())`